# How do I get the size of a set on Redis?

Tags: redis, set

For lists I can do the operation:

```
LLEN KeyName
```

and it will return the size of a list in Redis. What is the equivalent command for sets? I can't seem to find this in any documentation.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

You are looking for the [`SCARD`](http://redis.io/commands/scard) command:

> ### `SCARD key`
>
> Returns the set cardinality (number of elements) of the set stored at
>
> **Return value**
> Integer reply: the cardinality (number of elements) of the set, or 0 if key does not exist.
>
> **Time complexity:**
> O(1)

You can view all of the set commands on [the documentation webpage](http://redis.io/commands#set).

Comment: One of the most stupid thing about redis is that there are different commands to do the same thing depending on data type. Finding Length is one of these.

Comment: @Scalable those Redis engineers suck :) they could not think of it :)

Answer (score 4):

If it's a sorted set, you can use

```
ZCOUNT myset -inf +inf
```

or

```
ZCARD myset
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 2):

- `zCard` is short for cardinality (cardinality is the number of elements in a set). It gives you total number of members inside of a "sorted set".
- Sometimes you might wanna extract how many members are inside of a range in a sorted set. For that you can use `zCount`.

  ```
  ZCOUNT cars 0 50  // inclusive
  ```

this will include 0 and 55.  0 <= .... <=50. But if you do not want to include them

```
ZCOUNT cars (0 (50
```

- if it is regular set

  ```
  SCARD cars
  ```